# How to infer inner type of Shapeless record value with unary type constructor?

Tags: scala, type-inference, shapeless

I'm having trouble understanding the way the Shapeless record Selector interacts with scala's type inference.  I'm trying to create a method that can grab a field from a Shapeless record by key, only if the value of the field has a certain unary type constructor, in this particular case `Vector[_]`, and then grab an inner value of inferred type `V` out of the `Vector`, in this case with `Vector.apply()`.

I feel like I'm close.  This works, with a concrete inner type of `Int`:

```
val record = ( "a" ->> Vector(0,2,4) ) :: ( "b" ->> Set(1,3,5) ) :: HNil

def getIntFromVectorField[L <: HList](l: L, fieldName:Witness, index:Int)(implicit 
  sel: Selector.Aux[L, fieldName.T, Vector[Int]]
):Int = l(fieldName).apply(index)

getIntFromVectorField(record,"a",1) // Returns 1
getIntFromVectorField(record,"b",0) // Does not compile, as intended
```

But if I try to infer the inner type, it fails:

```
def getValueFromVectorField[L <: HList,V](l:L, fieldName:Witness, index:Int)(implicit 
  sel: Selector.Aux[L,fieldName.T,Vector[V]]
):V = l(fieldName).apply(index) // Compiles
getValueFromVectorField(record,"a",1) // Why does this not compile?
```

Here's the full error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter sel: 
shapeless.ops.record.Selector[shapeless.::[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] 
with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("a"),scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]],
shapeless.::[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] 
with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("b"),scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]],
shapeless.HNil]],String("a")]{type Out = scala.collection.immutable.Vector[V]}
```

What I have been able to do instead is this:

```
def getValueFromVectorField[L <: HList,T,V](l:L, fieldName:Witness, index:Int)(implicit 
  sel: Selector.Aux[L,fieldName.T,T], 
  unpack: Unpack1[T,Vector,V]
):V = l(fieldName) match { 
  case v:Vector[V] => v.apply(index) 
}
getValueFromVectorField(record,"a",1) // Returns 1, Yay!
getValueFromVectorField(record,"b",0) // Does not compile, as intended
```

Which should be safe, yes?  But the pattern matching doesn't feel very idiomatic for shapeless, and I'm wondering why the more concise approach with inference doesn't work.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala is really bad about type inference in cases like this (where you want to unify the result of a functional dependency and something like `Vector[V]` and have the `V` inferred).

You can help the compiler through the process by breaking down the steps:

```
import shapeless._, ops.record.Selector, syntax.singleton._

def getValueFromVectorField[L <: HList, VS, V](
  l: L,
  fieldName: Witness,
  index: Int
)(implicit
  sel: Selector.Aux[L, fieldName.T, VS],
  ev: VS <:< Vector[V]
): V = sel(l).apply(index)

val record = ( "a" ->> Vector(0,2,4) ) :: ( "b" ->> Set(1,3,5) ) :: HNil

getValueFromVectorField(record,"a",1) // Returns 1, Yay!
getValueFromVectorField(record,"b",0) // Does not compile, as intended
```

Now it'll infer `VS` first and then figure out that `VS` is a subtype of `Vector[V]`, instead of having to do both in one step.

This is exactly the same thing that your `Unpack1` version does, except that `Unpack1` only proves that `T` is `Vector[V]`—it doesn't actually give you a way to get a `Vector[V]` from a `T` (unlike `<:<`, which does).

So your `Unpack1` version is safe, in the sense that you can convince yourself that it provides all the pieces of evidence you need, but they're not in a form the compiler understands, so you have to downcast with the type case in the pattern match. `<:<` is better because the compiler does understand it, but also because it's more recognizable as a workaround for this limitation, since it's provided by the standard library, etc.