# HList foldLeft with tuple as zero

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

I'm trying to `foldLeft` on a HList with an accumulator of type `(HL, Int)`, where `HL` is a HList. The program below does not compile. However, if I switch to a simpler accumulator of type `HL` (by just switching the commented lines with the ones above), it compiles and it works.

Wrapping an HList in a tuple breaks the implicit resolution for the leftFolder. What am I missing?

```scala
package foo.bar

import shapeless.{:+:, ::, CNil, Coproduct, Generic, HList, HNil, Lazy, Poly2}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{LeftFolder, Reverse}

object StackOverflow extends App {

  trait MyTypeclass[T] {
    def doSomething(t: T): (T, Int)
  }

  implicit lazy val stringInstance: MyTypeclass[String] = (t: String) => (t, 0)
  implicit val hnilInstance: MyTypeclass[HNil] = (t: HNil) => (t, 0)
  implicit def hlistInstance[H, T <: HList](
    implicit
    head: Lazy[MyTypeclass[H]],
    tail: MyTypeclass[T]
  ): MyTypeclass[H :: T] =
    (ht: H :: T) =>
      ht match {
        case h :: t =>
          val (hres, hint) = head.value.doSomething(h)
          val (tres, tint) = tail.doSomething(t)
          (hres :: tres, hint + tint)
    }
  implicit val cnilInstance: MyTypeclass[CNil] = (t: CNil) => ???
  implicit def coproductInstance[L, R <: Coproduct](
    implicit
    head: Lazy[MyTypeclass[L]],
    tail: MyTypeclass[R]
  ): MyTypeclass[L :+: R] = (lr: L :+: R) => ???

  object leftFolder extends Poly2 {
    implicit def caseAtSimple[F, HL <: HList]: Case.Aux[HL, F, F :: HL] =
      at {
        case (acc, f) => f :: acc
      }
    implicit def caseAtComplex[F, HL <: HList]: Case.Aux[(HL, Int), F, (F :: HL, Int)] =
      at {
        case ((acc, i), f) => (f :: acc, i)
      }
  }

  implicit def genericInstance[T, HL <: HList, LL <: HList](
    implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL],
    myTypeclass: Lazy[MyTypeclass[HL]],
//    folder: LeftFolder.Aux[HL, HNil, leftFolder.type, LL],
    folder: LeftFolder.Aux[HL, (HNil, Int), leftFolder.type, (LL, Int)],
    reverse: Reverse.Aux[LL, HL]
  ): MyTypeclass[T] = (t: T) => {
    val generic = gen.to(t)
    val (transformed, idx) = myTypeclass.value.doSomething(generic)
//    val ll = transformed.foldLeft(HNil: HNil)(leftFolder)
    val (ll, _) = transformed.foldLeft((HNil: HNil, 0))(leftFolder)
    val reversed = reverse(ll)
    (gen.from(reversed), idx)
  }

  def doSomething[T](t: T)(implicit myTypeclass: MyTypeclass[T]): T = myTypeclass.doSomething(t)._1

  case class Foo(
    str1: String,
    str2: String
  )

  val original = Foo("Hello World!", "Hello there!")
  val result = doSomething(original)
  println(result == original)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want implicits to do too much work in a single step.

Try to add one more type parameter `Out`

```
implicit def genericInstance[T, HL <: HList, Out, LL <: HList](
  implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL],
  myTypeclass: Lazy[MyTypeclass[HL]],
  //folder: LeftFolder.Aux[HL, (HNil, Int), leftFolder.type, (LL, Int)],
  folder: LeftFolder.Aux[HL, (HNil, Int), leftFolder.type, Out],
  ev: Out <:< (LL, Int), // added
  reverse: Reverse.Aux[LL, HL]
): MyTypeclass[T] = (t: T) => {
  val generic = gen.to(t)
  val (transformed, idx) = myTypeclass.value.doSomething(generic)
  //val (ll, _) = transformed.foldLeft((HNil: HNil, 0))(leftFolder)
  val (ll, _) = ev(transformed.foldLeft((HNil: HNil, 0))(leftFolder))
  val reversed = reverse(ll)
  (gen.from(reversed), idx)
}
```

Read about over-constrained implicits:

https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:type-level-programming:chaining (4.3 Chaining dependent functions)

[Scala shapeless Generic.Aux implicit parameter not found in unapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432439/scala-shapeless-generic-aux-implicit-parameter-not-found-in-unapply)

[Extract FieldType key and value from HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259168/extract-fieldtype-key-and-value-from-hlist)

[How to implicitly figure out the type at the head of a shapeless HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960677/how-to-implicitly-figure-out-the-type-at-the-head-of-a-shapeless-hlist/)

[How to infer inner type of Shapeless record value with unary type constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308757/how-to-infer-inner-type-of-shapeless-record-value-with-unary-type-constructor/)

Comment: Still not compiling. I activated -Xlog-implicits, and I get the error: "hasMatchingSymbol reported error: Cannot prove that Out =:= (LL, Int)"

Comment: @pgrandjean Well, it seems to work with `=:=` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/erH3enRuREu0kN3RkxCOzA But if it works for you with `<:<`, so much the better.

Comment: @pgrandjean What are your Scala and Shapeless versions? At Scastie I used Scala 2.13.3 and Shapeless 2.4.0-M1.

Comment: Using Scala 2.12.12 and Shapeless 2.3.3

Comment: @pgrandjean Yeah, in 2.12.12+2.3.3 I can reproduce your error https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8MdBlFHkQ42mSUPVzvYdJg and confirm that `<:<` works https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vTFDEsGUQ7iDWtuSWN9qzg So this depends on versions used.

Comment: @pgrandjean Thanks for your edit proposal but I rejected it because `<:<` is not a method.

Comment: ok, no problem. I was just trying to use the same word used as in TTAGTS.

Comment: @pgrandjean If you're talking about *"Here’s a revised version of the method using `=:=` to constrain `Repr`..."* then "method" refers here to `def getWrappedValue`.

Comment: @pgrandjean Since `=:=` or `<:<` defines an implicit conversion you can replace the line `val (ll, _) = ev(transformed.foldLeft((HNil: HNil, 0))(leftFolder))` with just `val (ll: LL, _) = transformed.foldLeft((HNil: HNil, 0))(leftFolder)`.