# How to get Option[T] from object using Shapeless

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, shapeless

I was trying to get `Option[Author]` from `book` in `getAuthor` method:

```
  import shapeless.ops.record._

  case class Book(title: String, author: Option[Author])
  case class Author(name: String)
  val book = Book("Types and Programming Languages", Option(Author("Benjamin Pierce")))

  val w = Witness('author)
  def getAuthor[T1, T2 <: HList, T3](t: T1)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T1, T2], s: Selector.Aux[T2, w.T, Option[T3]]): s.Out = {
    val repr = gen.to(t)
    val opt = s.apply(repr)
    opt.foreach {
      ??? // do something
    }
    opt
  }

  val author = getAuthor(book)
  println(author)
```

but this code cause following compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter s: shapeless.ops.record.Selector.Aux[T2,shapeless.DuckTyping.w.T,Option[T3]] (No field shapeless.DuckTyping.w.T in record T2)
  val author = getAuthor(book)
```

I want to avoid compilation error and specify `Option[T]` as `Selector#apply` return value.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to over-constrain implicits.

Try to modify method signature

```
def getAuthor[T1, T2 <: HList, T3](t: T1)(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T1, T2],
  s: Selector.Aux[T2, w.T, T3],
  ev: T3 <:< Option[_]
): s.Out /* T3 */
```

[HList foldLeft with tuple as zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64688798/hlist-foldleft-with-tuple-as-zero)

[Why is this implicit resolution failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814539/why-is-this-implicit-resolution-failing)

[Scala shapeless Generic.Aux implicit parameter not found in unapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432439/scala-shapeless-generic-aux-implicit-parameter-not-found-in-unapply)

[Extract FieldType key and value from HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259168/extract-fieldtype-key-and-value-from-hlist)

[How to infer inner type of Shapeless record value with unary type constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308757/how-to-infer-inner-type-of-shapeless-record-value-with-unary-type-constructor/)

[How to implicitly figure out the type at the head of a shapeless HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960677/how-to-implicitly-figure-out-the-type-at-the-head-of-a-shapeless-hlist/)